# ¿Como establecer conexion de jdbc con Microsoft SQL Server magnament studio 18?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Al tratar de conectar la base de datos **Microsoft SQL Server magnament studio** desde el **IDE NetBeans 8.2** ocurre este error:

> **"Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-G55J81L:1433;databaseName=prueba using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (No se pudo realizar la conexión TCP/IP al host DESKTOP-G55J81L, puerto 1433. Error: "connect timed out. Verifique las propiedades de conexión, compruebe que hay una instancia de SQL Server ejecutándose en el host y aceptando las conexiones TCP/IP en el puerto y compruebe que no hay ningún firewall bloqueando las conexiones TCP en el puerto.".)"**.

Para comprobar que no era mi computadora, hice una conexión pero ahora con Mysql lo cual fue exitosa.

En la primer imagen se muestra el error en letras rojas y en la segunda se observa que se tienen los mismos puertos
[image: El error se muestra en letras rojas]

[image: Se muestra que están los mismos puertos]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola has intentado conectarte usando la ip local de tu computadora o colocando "." (si las comillas dobles) . Tambien prueba con el usuario sa , no se si en mssql hayas solo creado el usuario pero no le hayas asignado la base :o

Comment: @kiramishima no he intentado eso, en que parte pongo el punto, en el sql server configuration y en netbeans?, no se a que te refieres con una base, en Mysql use el nombre de servidor:localhost y use  el puerto predetermidado que es el 3306

Comment: En teoria deberias tener algo asi MSSQL -> Server DB,  SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) o Azure Data Studio & Netbeans. En el SSMS funciona como un Workbench para consultar.  Si en ese puedes entrar con el usuario `sa` con el password que le hayas asignado, debería funcionar en netbeans. En la conexión lo ideal es usar la IP de la máquina y no el nombre, puedes intentar: `jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.8.133:1433;database=AdventureWorks;user=sa;password=tupassword`

o

`jdbc:sqlserver://(localdb);database=AdventureWorks;user=sa;password=tupassword`

Comment: La ultima que se me podria venir a la mente es que no tengas el driver de mssql para jdbc instalado
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: En la parte de SQL native cliente verifica si en client protocols/TCP/IP estan habilitados

Comment: @kiramishima en la parte de JDBC URL inserte: jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.111:1433;database=prueba;user=sa;password=admin, dejando los espacios en blancos de la ventana, igual siguio dando el mismo error

Comment: @Draker edite la publicacion y subi la imagen de la revision que me sugeriste, si esta habilitado

Answer (score 0):

En el administrador de configuracion SQL, protocolos para MSSQLSERVER, en la pestaña IP Addresses, verifica que la IP de tu servidor SQL, esté habilitada y Activa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hecho esto reinicia el servicio MSSQL y utiliza la IP en la cadena de conexión JDBC:
`jdbc:sqlserver://tuIP:1433;database=tuBD;user=tuUser;password=tuPassword`

Comment: edite la publicacion agragandola una imagen donde se ve que ya tengo activado IP1, despues de eso reinicie MSSQL y en netbeans en la parte de @Harvwin Edil Perez Salinas   JDBC URL ingrese la siguiente cadena : "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.111:1433;database=prueba;user=prueba;password=admin", despues de hacer un test connection volvio aparecer el error                 Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.111:1433...

Comment: @Harvwin Edil Perez Salinas Edite la publicacion agragandola una imagen donde se ve que ya tengo activado IP1, despues de eso reinicie MSSQL y en netbeans en la parte de    JDBC URL ingrese la siguiente cadena : "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.111:1433;database=prueba;user=prueba;password=admin", despues de hacer un test connection volvio aparecer el error                 Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.111:1433...

Comment: Al parecer el puerto 1433 está bloqueado por algún tipo de firewall. Debes verificar eso. Puedes utilizar telnet para ello>  telnet 192.168.10.111 1433

Comment: Afirmativo, el puerto esta bloqueado, edite la pregunta agregando una imagen donde se muestra la prubea que esta bloqueado

Comment: cree el puerto 1433 y use el comando test y me aparece lo mismo "No se puede abrir la conexión al host, en puerto 1433: Error en la conexión", subi la imagen donde se ve qeu si cree el puerto 1433

Comment: Activa el browser del Sql server